# UITableView : sectionHeaderHeight from StoryBord not returned

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift2, swift3

I am translating from XCode 7.3 to Xcode 8.1 and from swift 2 to Swift 3.
I haven't change anything. In my project I have a UITableView with 2 sections. I have set a height of 28 in the storyboard for the sections.
[image]
[image]

When I ran on Xcode 7.3, my 2 section headers appear correctly but they disappear with Xcode 8.1. The reason is that I have this function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return (tableView.dataSource?.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section) > 0) ? tableView.sectionHeaderHeight : 0
}
```

When I inspect the value of tableView.sectionHeaderHeight, it is set at -1 instead of 28.

I have also this function

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}
```

Comment: Wow! It seems that if I set the SectionHeight at 27, 29, whatever number different from 28, it works ! How strange ! And it is impossible to have 28. could it be that the value is now "forbidden" because it comes from a "translated" storyboard (Xcode 7 to Xcode 8) ?